# How to clear all variable php , session , array when user log out?

Tags: php, arrays, session

How to clear all variable php , session , array when user log out ?

now i use `session_destroy();` for clear all session.

But i want to know how can i clear all php var and php array ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unset all variables in PHP script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247974/unset-all-variables-in-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

simple use unset variable like

```
session_destroy();
```

unset($_SESSION["id"]);
unset($_SESSION["userid"]);